# python, pandas, find average prices of the top four brands, dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Hi I need to get average prices of the top four brands, find the top four brands by the combined number of the categories, there are just three categories. the top four is not who has more money that is who has more products combine.

this is the dataframe:

```
brand     price   category
Apple     499.0    phone
Huawei    200.0    phone
Apple     150.0    headphones
Samsung   800.0    phone
Apple     55.0     accesory
xiomi     25.0     accesory
Huawei    140.0    headphones
```

this is the result I need, with brands as index with the avarage price of the four brands, with the price round in 2 decimals

```
         phone    headphones   accesory
brand_1  XXXX         XXXX        XXXX
brand_2  XXXX         XXXX        XXXX
brand_3  XXXX         XXXX        XXXX
brand_4  XXXX         XXXX        XXXX
```

I'm beginner so I don't have too much experience, I hope you can help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# get top 4 brands by size:
top_4 = df.groupby("brand").size().nlargest(4)

# pivot the table, format it and get top_4 brands:
df_out = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index="brand",
        columns="category",
        values="price",
        aggfunc="mean",
        fill_value=0,
    )
    .apply(lambda x: ["{:.2f}".format(v) for v in x])
    .loc[top_4.index]
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
category accesory headphones   phone
brand                               
Apple       55.00     150.00  499.00
Huawei       0.00     140.00  200.00
Samsung      0.00       0.00  800.00
xiomi       25.00       0.00    0.00
```

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Thanks! If I understand the question correctly - it's not *straight* pivoting - threre's searching for top 4 brands + formatting.

Comment: You're answer is correct but the OP should have first shown what they tried. I like the idea!